# What's the difference between refresh and source.refresh in CombinedLoadStates?

Tags: paging, android-paging-3, android-paging-library

If there is not remoteMediator, does this mean that `refresh` is the same to `source.refresh`?

It looks consistent from the logs, can someone give me an affirmative answer?

```
onCreateView: source.Refresh=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false)
onCreateView: source.Append=Loading(endOfPaginationReached=false)
onCreateView: source.Prepend=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=true)
onCreateView: Prepend=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=true)
onCreateView: Refresh=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false)
onCreateView: Append=Loading(endOfPaginationReached=false)
onCreateView: source.Refresh=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false)
onCreateView: source.Append=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false)
onCreateView: source.Prepend=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=true)
onCreateView: Prepend=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=true)
onCreateView: Refresh=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false)
onCreateView: Append=NotLoading(endOfPaginationReached=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, which is consistent with my conjecture.

```
private fun computeHelperState(
    previousState: LoadState,
    sourceRefreshState: LoadState,
    sourceState: LoadState,
    remoteState: LoadState?
): LoadState {
    
    if (remoteState == null) return sourceState // if the remoteState is null, return sourceState directly.
    
    return when (previousState) {
        is Loading -> when {
            sourceRefreshState is NotLoading && remoteState is NotLoading -> remoteState
            remoteState is Error -> remoteState
            else -> previousState
        }
        else -> remoteState
    }
}
```